# What is the sufficient condition of integration by parts?

Tags: integration

From the product rule of differentiation, we can derive $duv = udv + vdu$. By integrating the both side, we can get $uv = \int{udv} + \int{vdu}$.

What is the sufficient condition that allows this equation, $uv = \int{udv} + \int{vdu}$?

---

I was confused by the following two equations.

If $u=x$, $v=y$, then $xy = \int{xdy} + \int{ydx}$. This is wrong.

If $u=\cos\theta$, $v=\sin\theta$, then $\cos\theta\sin\theta = \int{\cos{\theta}d\sin\theta} + \int{\sin\theta d \cos\theta}$. This is correct.

Because both $\left(x,y\right)$ and $\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\right)$ are linear independent, it seems that the linear independence is not the sufficient condition of the integration by parts. Did I right? Or I was confused vectors with functions?

Comment: What do you think that $\int u\,dv$ means?

Comment: I think it means the sum of all $udv$ for all $u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example ($u=x$ and $v=y$), the two functions are functions of different variables. But in your second example ($u=\cos\theta$ and $v=\sin\theta$), although they are independent, they are both functions of $\theta$, and so they are related in that way. In your first example, if it was instead $u=x$ and $v=y(x)$, then integration by parts would work.

Comment: Although $x$ and $y$ are not related, but $dxy = xdy+ydx$ is still meaningful. Is it? $dxy = xdy+ydx$ is meaningful but $\int dxy = \int xdy+ \int ydx$ is not, so that  $u$ and $v$ is related is the sufficient condition allows integrating both sides of $duv = udv + vdu$?

Answer (score 0):

Take $u=f(x), v=g(x)$

What IBP states is that:

$$f(x)g(x)=\int{f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)\space dx}$$
Differentiating, we get:

$$[f(x)g(x)]'=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)$$

Which is just the product rule.

So as long as the two variables used are functions of the same variable, this holds.